# iphone table views with a preloader images

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I have table view to load data from an API call. I am using:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

for processing the result. I got the result, but my problem is when loading the first time table loaded with blank data. My requirement is to load an image showing "loading" when the data processing completed then load the table with the processed data. Please help me the preloading images in table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `UIActivityIndicatorView` for accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

1) After sending your request disable userinteraction of the UITableView, and show an [activity indicator](http://www.chrisdanielson.com/tag/uiactivityindicatorview/).

2) Your request can be successfull, or failure. NSURLConnection has suitable delegates for it.

> [- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection
>   *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/connection%3adidReceiveData%3a)
>
> [- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection
>   *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/connection%3adidFailWithError%3a)

Implement both of this, hide or remove activity indicator here. Enable tableView userinteraction and reload table.